# Enable HTTPS with Nginx, using Docker

Tags: docker, nginx, https

Ok. So I am trying to enable HTTPS with Nginx using Docker container.

My nginx.conf now looks like this:

```
    server {
      listen                443 ssl;
      server_name           localhost;
      ssl_certificate       ssl/domain.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key   ssl/domain.key;
      ssl_protocols         TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
      ssl_ciphers           HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
```

Btw I have a working version with HTTP, which looks like this:

```
server {
      listen                80;
      server_name           localhost;
```

When I am starting the docker container, I get an error saying: "[emerg] 1#1: cannot load certificate "/etc/nginx/ssl/domain.crt":"

I have created the encrypting with openssl, and it is put in the "ssl"-folder where the rest of my project is. But the problem seems to be here? Does anybody have a solution for this?

Comment: where is your domain.crt file and what are the permissions for the file

Comment: It is in the folder, where the rest of my project is. Read-permission. I have seen a lot of examples where the file is stored in something like /etc/nginx/.../...

Comment: change the `ssl/domain.crt;` to the absolute path to the certificate, or move the certificate to `/etc/nginx/ssl/`

Comment: Permissions should be restricted to the owner of the certififcate `-rw-------`